# Matching line items for bank reconciliation

Tags: excel, vba

I am preparing bank reconciliation file to match the **negative value with a positive one.** in below table there are negative values which need to be reconciled/match with the positive one. for example `A4 (5076)` is the sum of negative value `A2+A6+A8 (-5076)` which are reconciling each other and making zero. i want a excel coding which reconcile all the positive values with the negative values. please help

```
A      B
1    -5425
2    -4125
3    -2632
4     5076
5    -222
6    -906
7     8279
8    -45
9    -254
10   -542
```

Comment: I would say this is impossible as there are too many possible combinations if your data is longer. How many rows do you plan to have at maximum and how many additions of values should be possible?

Comment: What have you thought about or attempted? Would you search from the top each time? What would determine which of more than 1 set of matching values to choose?

Comment: For example if you have `200` rows and `4` additions can be made you have  `66,018,450` possible combinations to check which will already exceed Excel's limitation on possible calculations. Also you would easily run out of time.

Comment: If you have more than just columns that you mentioned above in the file, then you could create a composite key from those columns and then use the dictionary object to find matches and sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to be too big to fit in a comment, and may turn into an answer, so I'll post it as an answer.

I see a few questions at the beggining:

1. Is there a limit to how many rows can be involved in a given reconciliation (summation to 0)? Will only one of them be positive, or would {-2,-2,+1,+3} be a valid settlement?
2. Will *all* rows *always* reconcile? Or, to put the same question differently, what do you want your system to do when there are rows left over? Should it just crash?
3. Does it matter how the reconciliation groups are assigned? Consider the following example:

```
{(a, +5),
 (b, +4),
 (c, -1),
 (d, -1),
 (e, -2),
 (f, -2),
 (g, -3)}
```

Obviously that could be reconciled as

```
[{(a,+5), (c,-1), (d,-1), (g,-3)},
 {(b,+4), (e,-2), (f,-2)        }]
```

*or as*

```
[{(a,+5), (c,-1), (e,-2), (f,-2)},
 {(b,+4), (d,-1), (g,-3)        }]
```

but it's not clear *whether or not the difference matters*.

The most trivial case is if the answer to question #1 is "No, there's no limit", and the answer to question #2 is "All rows of a valid input list will always reconcile", and the answer to question #3 is "No it doesn't matter".
**In this situation your output is *allowed* to be a single reconciliation group containing all the rows.**

Assuming that's not what you want, you'll have to articulate what you want more clearly.

If the answer to question #3 is that difference between seemingly equivalent reconciliation groups *does* matter, then your solution will have to take into account information you haven't shown yet. While there might be a difference between `{(b,+4), (e,-2), (f,-2)}` and `{(b,+4), (d,-1), (g,-3)}`, there's not currently any way to *prefer* one over the other.

Likely you will run into the computational limitations pointed out in the comments. I'm not convinced that the task is *impossible*, but I would *strongly suggest* using something besides Excel or VBA.
A lot of people would try to do this in Python, which is fine. It looks to me like the kind of thing Haskell would be good at. If performance is an issue, then a low-level language like C, while not necessarily faster, may be easier to optimize.